# Can you hide the controls of a YouTube embed without enabling autoplay?

Tags: youtube

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/qUJYqhKZrwA?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

If you remove ?autoplay=1 the video does not work. Looks like you cannot use the controls parameter without autoplay enabled.

Not sure why this is not mentioned in the YouTube embed writeup.

Hope I'm wrong.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Set autoplay=0

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/qUJYqhKZrwA?autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

As seen here: [Autoplay=0 Test](http://anekiho.me/osaka/youtubetest.html)

Comment: Note: this no longer seems to work. YouTube most likely has changed their API - not sure what the current alternative/fix is.

Comment: One thing to note is a user could still use the right arrow key to skip ahead in the video. It seems each key press is a 5 second fast-forward/skip. If that is your goal, you would need to add the parameter &disablekb=1  which will disable all keyboard functionality (including play/pause from the keyboard).

Comment: `showinfo` is deprecated see in docs revision history announcement - [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

Answer (score 16):

To continue using the iframe YouTube, you should only have to change `?autoplay=1` to `?autoplay=0`.

Another way to accomplish this would be by using the YouTube JavaScript Player API. (https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)

**Edit: the YouTube JavaScript Player API is no longer supported.**

```
<div id="howToVideo"></div>

<script type="application/javascript">

    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = false;
    ga.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/player_api';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

    var done = false;
    var player;

    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('howToVideo', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'qUJYqhKZrwA',
        playerVars: {
            controls: 0,
            disablekb: 1
        },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(evt) {
        console.log('onPlayerReady', evt);
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
        console.log('onPlayerStateChange', evt);
        if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
            setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
            done = true;
        }
    }

    function stopVideo() {
        console.log('stopVideo');
        player.stopVideo();
    }

</script>
```

Here is a jsfiddle for the example: http://jsfiddle.net/fgkrj/

Note that player controls are disabled in the "playerVars" part of the player.  The one sacrifice you make is that users are still able to pause the video by clicking on it.  I would suggest writing a simple javascript function that subscribes to a stop event and calls `player.playVideo()`.

Comment: can you set autoplay 0 in the playerVars?

Comment: Isn't JS API supported when adding &enablejsapi=1 parameter?

Comment: What evidence is there that the JS api is no longer supported? There is no notice on the documentation stating so.

Answer (score 7):

use `autoplay=0`

autoplay takes 2 values.

```
Values: 0 or 1. Default is 0. Sets whether or not the initial video will autoplay when the player loads.
```

the important part

```
autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0
```

Here is the demo for ur problem [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/7fDU6/)

Answer (score 4):

```
?modestbranding=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=0

autohide=1
```

is something that I never found... but it was the key :) I hope it's help

Answer (score 3):

If you add this `?showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&controls=0` before the end of your `src`, it will take out everything but the bottom right YouTube logo

 working example: http://jsfiddle.net/42gxdf0f/1/

Answer (score 2):

Follow this https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters for more info about video controls like:

```
<iframe id="video_iframe" width="660" height="415" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{{course_url}}?start=7&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&rel=0"
                frameborder="0"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**start=7&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&rel=0"
frameborder="0"**

> all controls are described in there

Answer (score 0):

To remove you tube **`controls`** and **`title`** you can do something like this

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zP0Wnb9RI9Q?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

[code with output](https://jsfiddle.net/umanguSp/pt5gcv2r/)

`showinfo=0` is used to remove title and `&controls=0` is used for remove controls like **volume**,**play**,**pause**,**expend**.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the "Watch Later" Button by using "Youtube-nocookie" (this will not hide the share Button)

Adding **`controls=0`** will also remove the video control bar at the bottom of the screen and using **`modestbranding=1`** will remove the youtube logo at bottom right of the screen

However using them both doesn't works as expected (it only hides the video control bar)

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/fNb-DTEb43M?controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

Autoplay works only with `/v/` instead of `/embed/`, so change the src to:

`src="//www.youtube.com/v/qUJYqhKZrwA?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=0"`

Comment: The autoplay parameter works with /embed/ links for me.