# Disable clicking on the play button in video carousel

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

![enter image description here][1]At the moment i can click on any video in the carousal and it will appear in the iframe , where i am just taking the src of the video. I wanted to know if there a way to stop allowing the user to play the video when its in the carousal, but only play when the video is inside the iframe.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="main">
    <iframe width="600" height="480" id="mainvideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DU6UV2GPzIk?" style="margin: 30px auto 10px;float: none;display: block;" src="" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">

        <div class="article-video red" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DU6UV2GPzIk?"></a></div>
        <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2ZfqGr7HbEo?"></a></div>
        <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/053yP1wQR_s?"></a></div>
        <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/B-QIFAy6LPI?"></a></div>
        <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4_ZRUC0g1ic?"></a></div>
        <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YU6AU-khKuo?"></a></div>
        <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bkz5wyb_6j8?"></a></div>
        <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/f1kx4Bce6nI?"></a></div>
        <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1HTq4F_js2g?"></a></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Jquery code  i am using to change the video in the IFrame.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".article-video").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href= $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        var target = $('.article-video').index($(this));
        $("#mainvideo").attr("src", href);

    })
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
        owl.owlCarousel({
            items:4,
            margin:20,
            loop:true,
            video:true,
            lazyLoad:true,
            dots:false,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
                },

                678:{
                    items:3
                },
                1000:{
                    items:4
                }
            },
            nav:true,
            navText: [
                "<i class='icon-chevron-left icon-white'><</i>",
                "<i class='icon-chevron-right icon-white'>></i>"
            ]

        });
    });

$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".article-video").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var href= $(this).find('a').attr('href');
            var target = $('.article-video').index($(this));
            $("#mainvideo").attr("src", href);

        })
    });
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jackpotjoy.com/promo/responsive_templates/Test/assets/css/demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jackpotjoy.com/promo/responsive_templates/Test/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jackpotjoy.com/promo/responsive_templates/Test/owlcarousel/owl.theme.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="main">
        <iframe width="600" height="480" id="mainvideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DU6UV2GPzIk?" style="margin: 30px auto 10px;float: none;display: block;" src="" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

        <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">

            <div class="article-video red" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DU6UV2GPzIk?controls=0"></a></div>
            <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2ZfqGr7HbEo?controls=0"></a></div>
            <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/053yP1wQR_s?controls=0"></a></div>
            <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/B-QIFAy6LPI?controls=0"></a></div>
            <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4_ZRUC0g1ic?"></a></div>
            <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YU6AU-khKuo?"></a></div>
            <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bkz5wyb_6j8?"></a></div>
            <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/f1kx4Bce6nI?"></a></div>
            <div class="article-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1HTq4F_js2g?"></a></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="http://www.jackpotjoy.com/promo/responsive_templates/Test/assets/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jackpotjoy.com/promo/responsive_templates/Test/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its just a youtube video

Comment: Your question could use some more info. Can you set up a [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)?

Comment: I've made a  fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/31muLtex/ I can see that clicking on the owl thumbnail is changing the src attribute of the youtube video. So that part is working. Unfortunately youtube is blocked by my work proxy so I can test any more.

Comment: Have a look here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls can you not set controls=0 for <a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DU6UV2GPzIk?"></a>

Comment: I tried this but the video still playing in the carousel

Comment: I have updated the question with a code snippet

Comment: Maybe it is not possible using the embed option. But it might be if you use the API. There is a bit more info here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20951500/1238244, but this seems to discuss the iframe source. What if you remove the embed option from the url inside the .owl-video class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
$('.owl-video-play-icon').remove();
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/31muLtex/4/

(I tried to disable the click event on the .owl-video-play-icon but it didn't work, presumably it is being fired later by the youtube js, it does mean there could be another solution, but this does prevent the video from being played in the thumbnail).