# Hide YouTube video controls (Title, Watch later, Share) using HTML / CSS / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am embedding Youtube / Daily Motion Videos in my website...

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/an-6owXUwdg" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

I don't want the Youtube Videos Controls to be visible on my website...

Please look at the attached files, i want to remove the controls which are at the top (Highlighted in Red Color) and also want to remove controls which are at the bottom (Highlighted in Red Color).

[image]
[image]

Previously it was possible in youtube videos using showinfo parameter. Now that parameter is deprecated, reference(https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#showinfo)

Is there any other way to do that using HTML / CSS / JavaScript

OR

Can i run youtube videos on any player and can fulfill my requirements?

Comment: Have you tried this ? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710764/can-you-hide-the-controls-of-a-youtube-embed-without-enabling-autoplay) and also this one [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418028/youtube-javascript-api-disable-related-videos)

Comment: Not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

The old way of doing this looked like:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/an-6owXUwdg?controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

I added ?controls=0&showinfo=0 to the query string.

Unfortunately, when I tried it, it no longer worked. Upon further research I found that the ability to hide what you would like to has been removed. 
See the information here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#showinfo

"Note: This parameter is deprecated and will be ignored after September 25, 2018."

So currently there is no way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Youtube Iframe. It won't work because Youtube has deprecated the parameter to control title, share and watch-later option.

Other ways to solve this:
Try other video players for this, something like videojs or even service like
vimeo provides custmisation of the video player.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So far there is no working way we could add css in iframe specially for YT Players to hide title, youtube logo.

Have tried to inject styles but it does work.

```js
const iframeYT = document.querySelector(".iframe-wrapper iframe");
const style = document.createElement("style");
style.textContent = `
  .ytp-chrome-top.ytp-show-cards-title,
    .ytp-gradient-top,
    .ytp-gradient-bottom {
      display: none;
    }
    a.ytp-watermark.yt-uix-sessionlink.ytp-watermark-small {
      display: none;
    }
`;
iframeYT.contentDocument.head.appendChild(style);
console.dir(iframeYT.contentDocument);
```

```html
<div class="iframe-wrapper">
  <iframe width="500" height="280" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pX8s7WF3sC8?autoplay=1&mute=1&controls=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&rel=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
    allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Luckily, a css-hack along with `?autoplay=1&mute=1&controls=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&rel=0` works out pretty fine.
It does hide the video title and the youtube logo from iframe. Hope it'll work out for you too.

```css
.iframe-wrapper {
  height: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.iframe-wrapper iframe {
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe-wrapper">
  <iframe width="500" height="280" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pX8s7WF3sC8?autoplay=1&mute=1&controls=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&rel=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
    allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

[Check this demo](https://output.jsbin.com/zukasux/1?html,css,output)

Answer (score -1):

This is very common issue while we `embedding` videos in HTML, So We fix this issue with a simple trick, we will create a parent (wrapper) div of `iframe` and add `padding-bottom: 56.25%`. This is where the magic is. In CSS, the padding-bottom property can receive a percentage, this is what keeps our iframe to the right ratio. By using percentage.

```css
.parent{
    height: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.parent iframe{
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Didn't do anything for me. Do you have any working example?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube

[codepen.io/vinukumar-vs/pen/GRgpeqE](http://codepen.io/vinukumar-vs/pen/GRgpeqE)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video-js.min.css">
    <video
      id="vid1"
      class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
      width="640" height="264"
      data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ"}]}'
    >
    </video>
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-youtube/2.6.0/Youtube.min.js"></script>
```